# how to play next sound clip on single button click action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am making an app where I have 10 sound clips(mp3, short clips) and 10 images, images are of fruits and on each fruit image I want that particular fruit soundclip to play . On Play Button click.

For ref look at my code... which plays a single clip

.h file

```
@interface FruitsViewController : UIViewController

{

     SystemSoundID fruitSound;   
}
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)btnPlayClicked:(id)sender {

     NSURL * soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]     
URLForResource:@"fruits_s_01" withExtension:@"mp3"];        
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &fruitSound);        

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(fruitSound);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your fruit Images with the Music Files with 2 arrays

```
for example if there is an image as "1" then load the music files "Music1"
```

In such a manner you can traverse to and fro from an array and play the music file by loading it in the AudioPlayer instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the names of sound files in an array and make this array as property or private in your class where you have your fruitSound variable. The on each click on btnPlayClicked increment the array and get the name of the file from it and pass it to urlforresource. Hope it helps. :)